# comment_form() does not work (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to add comment form to my custom template of page but it doesn't work (I mean the comment form does not appear). I don't know why because I think it must work. 
Template file **reviews.php**:

```
<?php 
/*
 * Template Name: Reviews
 */
 get_header(); ?>
<div class="container page">
    <h2>Отзывы</h2>
    <?php comment_form();?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Structure of folder with theme:
[structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYssA.png)

Could you tell me please what is a reason of my problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

YOU must enter in admin and check in if commments are open in this specific post-type/page.

Im not sure but... Pages for example, dont show commments by default

Just enter admin pages and enable comments and form need to appear..

```
    <?php comment_form();?>

    <?php

// Other way calling comments.php. If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) :

    comments_template();

endif;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know about it! 
I have another problem. The comment form doesn't appear! Users wont be able to send me different information because there aren't any forms

Answer (score 0):

i dont see any comment template in your files. and i dont know if wp support/work nicely without this for discussions.

so my suggestion is copy comments.php file from any wp defult template. or just create  comments.php file in your theme.

```
if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) :
comments_template();
//this will load comments.php 
// and course will call comment_form function too..
endif;
```

Another valid option is enable disqus plugin to handle site comments